# Profiling Node.js using DTrace

Tags: javascript, node.js, profiling, dtrace

I am currently profiling my node.js application.I found this blog: http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/04/25/profiling-node-js/ that suggests I should use Dtrace.
I installed dtrace on ubuntu 12.04 using steps given here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/60940/how-do-i-install-dtrace

However when I run this command in my terminal while my node application is running:

```
dtrace -o stacks.out -n 'profile-97/execname == "node" && arg1/{
@[jstack(100, 8000)] = count(); } tick-60s { exit(0); }'
```

stacks.out remains blank except this:
CPU     ID                    FUNCTION:NAME
  1 387695                        :tick-60s

Any suggestions what might be wrong?

Comment: With latest node.js in Linux you could have a look at Systemtap. I do not know how much is supported. Measure GC => https://gist.github.com/bnoordhuis/4078925. I have not played with this yet but looks promising/interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Linux DTrace implementations are currently very young and missing a number of important features (and are not in any way ready for production use). Specifically the DTrace implementation you are using (Paul Fox's) has not done much if any work to support userspace tracing. So you will not be able to do this under Linux (right now).

If you want to get this to work you will need to use an operating system with a more complete implementation of DTrace. You're best bet is to use one of the [Illumos](http://wiki.illumos.org) derivatives (such as [OmniOS](http://omnios.omniti.com/), [SmartOS](http://smartos.org/) or [OpenIndiana](http://openindiana.org/)).

You should re-read the 'prerequisites' section of the [the article you linked to](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/04/25/profiling-node-js/). It states that you also need to make sure you use 32bit NodeJS with DTrace support turned on at compile time.

(Mac OS X does have a good DTrace implementation, but according to [the article](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/04/25/profiling-node-js/) it does not support ustack helpers which are needed for this example.)

Comment: To install node.js on OmniOS (Illumos based OS): https://gist.github.com/dalssoft/5595688

Answer (score 3):

@psanford has a good answer specifically involving your issues with DTrace, but from your opening sentence, it looks like what you *want* is to be able to trace your Node.js app, and DTrace was just one example on how to do so.

In that case, a combination of [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector) and [v8-profiler](https://github.com/dannycoates/v8-profiler) would provide you with the desired introspection into your application. I'm not sure if it works with Node 0.6.x, however, since the last time I used it was with 0.4.10.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle [announced](https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/entry/announcement_dtrace_for_oracle_linux) DTrace availability on **Oracle Linux**.
You can download this distro [here](https://edelivery.oracle.com/linux).